# scala library incompatibility with jwi

Tags: scala, wordnet

I have written the code for accessing the similarity between two words using wordnet. There is no errors in it. I have used the MIT Java Wordnet Interface for accessing wordnet. I am getting a build error

```
edu.mit.jwi_2.4.0.jar of .. build path is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.4.0).
```

The code is not a problem but the scala IDE version is 2.11. There does not appear to be a more recent version of the jar online. Deleting the jar and removing the build path results in required library not found error.

How do I do this very simple task???

EDIT>>>>

I cannot find any jar for jwi after 2012. Can someone suggest an alternative to retrieve similarity between words??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is misleading, underscores are usually used to describe scala versions. The JWI guys didn't put their JAR on maven, so somehow they managed to give you wierd jar-names... try replacing the `_` in the name with a `-` and message them to put their jars on maven.

Comment: cannot find any jar after 2.4 anywhere. Not on the maven repository nor as a download. The last one on maven repo is 2.2.3 from the year 2012 jar

Comment: Changed the underscore to hyphen. Downloaded the WordNet-InfoContent-WordNet-3.0 folder and put it under WordNet-3.0 folder. Finally running. The last update to jwi is  july 2015, so dont know if it will be supported for long. Anyways thanks for pointing out the underscore thing